# Single-Variable Binding in Win Forms: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I've been trying to make binding work for two labels in a WinForm, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Currently, I'm implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and rigged it to a couple of properties within a Form. The current classes this affects are `SessionForm.cs`, the actual form, and `Session.cs`, the place where I keep all the information of the program. The labels in question, which are not mentioned in either class, are L_No, which holds the numerical reference of the Note in the musical Scale, and L_Note, which holds the visceral Note value (e.g. C, C#, etc.).

Allow me to explain what everything does within the classes. The program is designed to test your scale knowledge by asking you, based on the your chosen scale, what n<sup>th</sup> note of the scale is. You use the buttons on the form to make your choice.

These choices are recorded within the Session class, which has been edited to make this more succinct. The array of integers holds the indices of the notes in relation to the scale array, which is in the `Scale` object. For example, a typical `Note` array may hold these values: `{1,3,0,2,6,1,3,...}`. By using the array in the `Scale` object as a reference, these would translate into musical notes (e.g. D, F, C, E, B, D, F,...). The player's choices are stored within an array of `NoteData` objects.

In `SessionForm.cs` I'm manipulating that information over time. Each time a choice is or isn't made (depending on whether or not they attempted to guess in time), the value of the two Labels are changed: L_No, and L_Note. These two Labels are manipulated by the variables NoteIndex and LastNote, respectively. When these change in value, NotifyPropertyChanged occurs, and then the Labels *should* be updated...but they're not doing so.

Now, in the design section of the form, in the Properties window, I set up the Text property of each Label to be bound to their respective variables within the form, and set to update upon Property Change, but nothing seems to be working.

So what am I doing wrong?

**Session.cs**:

```
    public class Session
    {
        public struct NoteData
        {
            public int Note;
            public bool Correct;
            public int GuessTime;
        }

        public Scale Scale;

        /// <summary>
        /// Holds the notes for one game
        /// </summary>
        public int[] Notes { get; private set; }

        public NoteData[] Data { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a  Session
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="difficulty">The difficult of the session, refer to the Resources Class for determination.</param>
        /// <param name="scale_used">The scale to be used. Refer to the Resources Class for determination.</param>
        /// <param name="notes">The notes being used within this Session</param>
        public Session(Resources.Difficulties difficulty, Scale scale_used, int[] notes)
        {
            ID = DateTime.Now;
            Diff = difficulty;
            Scale = scale_used;
            Notes = notes;
            Data = new NoteData[notes.Length];
            internalIndex = 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stores Note input for each guessed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index">The index of the note the player is currently on</param>
        /// <param name="correct">Was the guess correct?</param>
        /// <param name="remaining_time">How long did it take for them to guess?</param>
        public void StoreNoteInput(int index, bool correct, int remaining_time)
        {
            if (internalIndex < Data.Length)
                Data[internalIndex++] = new NoteData(index, remaining_time, correct);
        } 


}
```

**SessionForm.cs**:

```
    public partial class SessionForm : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Session curSession { get; private set; }
        Resources.Notes last_note;
        /// <summary>
        /// The note index number in relation to the scale
        /// </summary>
        public int NoteIndex
        {
            get
            { return note_index; }
            private set
            {
                if (note_index != value)
                {
                    note_index = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("NoteIndex");
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Represents the previous note being tested
        /// </summary>
        public Resources.Notes LastNote
        {
            get
            {
                return last_note;
            }
            private set
            {
                if (last_note != value)
                {
                    last_note = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("LastNote");
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void TickDownTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            remainingTime -= countingDown ? 1000 : 100;
            if (remainingTime == 0)
            {
                if (countingDown)
                {
                    countingDown = false;
                    TickDownTimer.Interval = 100;
                }
                if (curIndex > 0)
                {
                    //you ran out of time on the last note
                    RecordNoteInput(curIndex - 1, false);


                }
                NextNote();
            }
            SetTimerText();
        }

        private void RecordNoteInput(int index, bool correct)
        {
            curSession.StoreNoteInput(index, correct, remainingTime);
            NoteIndex = curSession.Notes[curIndex - 1];
            LastNote = curSession.Scale.Notes[NoteIndex];
            L_Note.ForeColor = correct ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: Here's the binding code that comes from `SessionForm.Designer.cs`:

```
            this.sessionFormBindingSource1 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            this.sessionFormBindingSource2 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            this.sessionFormBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            // 
            // L_Note
            // 
            this.L_Note.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.sessionFormBindingSource1, "LastNote", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, "C"));
            this.L_Note.Text = " ";
            // 
            // L_No
            // 
            this.L_No.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.sessionFormBindingSource2, "NoteIndex", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, "1", "N0"));
            this.L_No.Text = " ";
```

Comment: have you verified that `NotifyPropertyChanged` is fired? Also, while I appreciate your attempt to be thorough, there is a **lot** going on above your code samples. You would be more likely to get help if you can strip out all the 'noise' and just describe the problem you're having with binding, i.e. "The label `L_NoteNo` is bound to `NoteIndex` but it doesn't change when the value of `NoteIndex` changes."

Comment: @DrewJordan: I did check, no, I didn't fire, and I don't know why, and I shortened the OP. I added the extra just in case I missed something you would be able to see the system working, instead of just the problem. I could have done that, but you wouldn't understand what else is happening along with it that might be messing with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way you call `NotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("note_index");
```

and

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("last_note");
```

Just remove the strings from the calls like this

```
NotifyPropertyChanged();
```

and everything should be fine.

**Edit:** If it's not, then your bindings are not initialized correctly. Prove:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tests
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new TestForm());
        }
    }
    class TestForm : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public TestForm()
        {
            var label = new Label { Parent = this, Left = 16, Top = 16, AutoSize = false, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle };
            label.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "NoteIndex");
            var timer = new Timer { Interval = 200, Enabled = true };
            timer.Tick += (sender, e) => NoteIndex = (NoteIndex + 1) % 10;
        }
        int note_index;
        public int NoteIndex
        {
            get { return note_index; }
            private set
            {
                if (note_index != value)
                {
                    note_index = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that first...didn't work. The potential fix WAS the parameter inclusion.

Comment: @SageKelly No, it's not a fix, it's a bug. The `NotifyPropertyChanged` should be called with the **property** name, not **field** name. Try again. If it doesn't work, show the code that creates bindings.

Comment: I switched it to what you said, and there's still no change. See OP for update.

Comment: @SageKelly It starts getting boring. In addition to the bugs addressed in the answer, **Obviously** your bindings and/or sources are not initialized correctly. Have you looked at my example above - I'm binding to the form instance - which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and contains the data. Now look at yours - your are binding to 2 separate `BindingSource` components. Where is `this.sessionFormBindingSource1.DataSource = this` and `this.sessionFormBindingSource1.DataSource = this;`? What are you expecting to get from these empty binding sources? If they are not empty, where is the code?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying this before the posted "fix"/bug, but I didn't know I was supposed to use "this" as the second parameter. I was using a BindingSource variable instead, like an MSDN website told me to do. Your solution worked. Now I'm off to fix my other variable.

Comment: @SageKelly There is nothing wrong to use `BindingSource` at design time. Just make sure you connect it to the real data in runtime. In your case use the form load event and put the lines highlighted in the previous comment:  `this.sessionFormBindingSource1.DataSource = this;` (I know it looks a bit weird:-)) and `this.sessionFormBindingSource2.DataSource = this;` and everything should be fine. For more info, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx. Cheers.